# How to figure out if the memory is bad?

Tags: ram

I recently had a problem where the computer (Thinkpad E430) hang while booting and I suspect that it is a bad memory issue. Checkbox test fail on memory, but memtest86+ passed. After removing the memory and re-installing I managed to boot the computer. However, the memory information looks odd:

1. I have 4GB or RAM and running ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

   ```
   sudo lshw -class memory:
   *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: a
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: HMT351S6CFR8C-PB
             vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
             physical id: 0
             serial: 0A545936
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             **size: 4GiB**
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
   ```
2. System monitor shows that there is only 2.6GB available and more than 50% is used even though I don't run any program:
   [System Monitor image after boot without running any program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atzol.png)

   ```
   grep Memory /var/log/kern.log:

   kernel: [    0.000000] Memory: 2562464K/**2730856K available** (8432K kernel code, 1291K rwdata, 3960K rodata, 1484K init, 1316K bss, 168392K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
   ```

How can I figure out if there is a problem in the RAM or elsewhere?

Comment: Can you please add the output of `cat /proc/meminfo` to your question?

Comment: Looks fine. However, in most modern machines, you'd add similar size/kind/speed memory in pairs, so you can take advantage of memory interleaving, for speed. If you were to add memory now, you'd want to add another 4G stick.

Comment: cat /proc/meminfo

Comment: MemTotal:        2602744 kB
MemFree:          110756 kB
MemAvailable:     148336 kB
Buffers:           18716 kB
Cached:           598856 kB
SwapCached:        51144 kB
Active:          1485224 kB
Inactive:         799088 kB
Active(anon):    1355032 kB
Inactive(anon):   711628 kB
Active(file):     130192 kB
Inactive(file):    87460 kB
Unevictable:        2480 kB
Mlocked:            2480 kB
SwapTotal:       2729980 kB
SwapFree:        1081376 kB
Dirty:               172 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1626268 kB

Comment: Mapped:           312972 kB
Shmem:            399888 kB
Slab:              76752 kB
SReclaimable:      34952 kB
SUnreclaim:        41800 kB
KernelStack:       12064 kB
PageTables:        56164 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     4031352 kB
Committed_AS:    9933100 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    387072 kB

Comment: CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      181496 kB
DirectMap2M:     2549760 kB

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest booting from USB memory stick (e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). Also make sure to use 64 bit variant if you still can find 32 bit version somewhere.

The fact that `lshw` lists memory funny is not unexpected. The system I'm currently using has 4x8 GB of DDR3 memory and `lshw` listing looks basically like this:

```
  *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 1
     *-bank UNCLAIMED
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: 99U5471-036.A00LF
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: 6B2B875D
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
  *-memory:1
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 5e
       slot: System board or motherboard
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: KHX1600C10D3/8GX
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: B804123E
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: 99U5471-036.A00LF
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 1
          serial: 692B865D
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: KHX1600C10D3/8GX
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 2
          serial: B704D03D
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
  *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 2
  *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 3
```

Note how `memory:0` seems to have one `UNCLAIMED` bank which has one stick and `memory:1` has three sticks and `memory:2` and `memory:3` are empty.

The `slot:` names seem to be okay so I would only trust those.

However, looking through `sudo dmidecode` output, it seems that this may be due BIOS bug because DMI seems to tell similar configuration for memory.

In the end, if `grep "MemTotal" /proc/meminfo` does not match the actual memory (minus GPU memory reserved for integrated graphics), then Linux cannot use all of your actual memory. If that is the case, I'd try to look for BIOS updates or try faking OS for ACPI: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DSDT. In case of broken bios, you could also try `noacpi` kernel flag which will disable e.g. power management as a side-effect but will help with most ACPI/BIOS problems.